# How to transform frames so axis align

Tags: tf2, calibration, coordinate-system, transformation

I have the location of two sensors, S_1 and S_2 with frames attached to each and I have the frame Transformation that gives S_2 location and orientation with respect to S_1.

Additionally I have a third frame S_3 which uses a different set of axis also attached to S_2.

I am confused on how to relabel the axis in a way so that S_2frame can be written with respect to S_3.

The basic issue is the sensors are calibrated with respect to each other using a different coordinate system and I'm having trouble aligning them in the coordination system used by TF2